# an error upon installation

Tags: xubuntu, ubuntu-bug

Please help me to resolve this error.

```
Package dependencies cannot be resolved


This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.


Details>>


The following packages have unmet dependencies:

wings3d: Depends: erlang-base-hipe (>= 1:15.b.1-dfsg) but 1:15.b.1-dfsg-3ubuntu2 is to be installed
         Depends: erlang-abi-15.b but it is a virtual package
         Depends: erlang-wx (>= 1:15.b.1-dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: erlang-xmerl (>= 1:15.b.1-dfsg) but 1:15.b.1-dfsg-3ubuntu2 is to be installed
         Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.15-0ubuntu20 is to be installed
         Depends: libjpeg8 (>= 8c) but 8c-2ubuntu7 is to be installed
```

Im using ubuntu 12.10

This help me to fix this.. thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

i assume this is after an `apt-get` command? if yes, run `apt-get update` and make sure there's no 404 or other download errors on the list before trying again.

if you are using the ubuntu software store (argh), then click any button called refresh... ok, i just checked. there's none.... so ignore this line.

if you using GUI, run Software Updater. it will refresh the list automatically. and then open the software store and try again whatever you were trying.